# C#: convert string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I want to parse strings with date that can have different formats like:

"21.12.12", "4,12,2011", "30 Jun 11", "16 12 2013" , "April 2013", "12. April 2012", "12, März 2011".

I have this code:

```
string[] ll = {"en-US", "de-DE"}; 
date = "4,12,2011";
foreach (string l in ll) {
   if (DateTime.TryParse(date, new CultureInfo(l),
                            DateTimeStyles.None, out pDate)) {
       return pDate;//.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
   }
}
```

And I have problems with dates like this:

> ***"21.12.12"*** is parsed like ***"21 December 2012"***, and it is OK
>
> ***"4,12,2011"*** is parsed like ***"12 April 2011"***, it is not OK, I need "4 December 2011"

***How to set order for Day and Month?***

It must be ***Day before Month***.

Comment: 4,12,2011 is a *valid* string for both April 12th and December 4th. The code has no way of knowing which is the one meant unless you specify the format.

Comment: I swear, this is asked soooooo many times. It's definently a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is specific for the `en-US` culture. It may be strange for us Europeans, but Americans really write month before day in dates. You may use `en-GB` instead - it will handle the same names of months and the European order.

Answer (score 3):

To specify the format(s) of the string you are passing, you should use the [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) method.

Comment: But if you don't know what the exact format is this doesn't help unless you can suggest code that would happily parse "21.12.12" and "12. April 2012" just as easily... Cultures are the way to go...

Comment: The point was why bother using parse exact and specifying a lot of different formats rather than just using parse and let it try all the formats it can think of if that works once you sort out the culture problems...

Comment: @Chris ok, now I got it :) You are absolutely right, +1 to your answer from me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`, it has also an overload tha allows to pass a `string[[]` for all allowed formats.

```
string[] dates = new[] { "21.12.12", "4,12,2011", "30 Jun 11", "16 12 2013", "April 2013", "12. April 2012", "12, März 2011" };
CultureInfo germanCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"); // you are using german culture
string[] formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yy", "d,MM,yyyy", "dd MMM yy", "dd MM yyyy", "MMMM yyyy", "dd. MMMM yyyy", "dd, MMMM yyyy"};

foreach (string dateString in dates)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, germanCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
}
```

I have used german culture because your date-strings contain german month names. So this code works even if the current culture is different.

Comment: You don't need parse exact if you have the right culture. Using `Parse` and the `de-DE` culture all of those strings work without having to try to cover every possibility with formats.

Answer (score 2):

All of the test dates that you gave actually parse correctly in the `de-DE` culture that you specify. The problem comes that you try to parse it in the american culture first where they use `mm.dd.yyyy` style formats.

The correct solution in general is to always make sure you know what culture you are using when parsing the string rather than guessing. If you have to guess you will get these kinds of problems at times.

In this case though it looks like they are all acceptable `de-DE` date strings so you can just parse them as that without needing the loop of trying different cultures (which as mentioned is probably never likely to be a perfect result).

Comment: +1 for "all dates parse correctly", i didn't test that even though my culture is "de-De" ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I tested largely because I was curious about why the en-us was in there in the first place. It was clearly the cause of the problem so I was trying to work out what other problem it was there to solve. Then I found it was no other problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to your code

```
  string[] ll = {"en-US", "de-DE"};
```

you initially try parse DateTime with "en-US" culture; so the "4,12,2011" will be parsed 
as americans do - MM/DD/YYYY - month the first (12 April). Change order in your array

```
  string[] ll = {"de-DE", "en-US"};
```

and "4,12,2011" will be 4 December